# How can I make sure my curve is not overlapping?

Tags: edit-mode

As you can see in the picture below, my curve is overlapping on the inside. How can I make sure it does not overlap?
I want to have this radius, so I don't want to make it smaller.

Here is the blend file just in case: [image]

[image]

Comment: You want to keep both the bending radius and the diameter of the pipe?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would not have an issue if I would just reduce the diameter of the pipe. But i want to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any way to fix it, other than to remove some of your control points:

[image]

Or convert to mesh and correct the topology:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not an engineer so my explanation won't be very technical. The approach to modeling this 90 degree smooth bend part is purely observational.

One can see that in *normal* cases the pipe bend can be split in two cylinders and a quarter of a torus with minor radius equal to the radius of the cylinders:

[image: The center of the torus is outside the pipes]

*The center of the torus is outside the pipes.*

If you keep the radius of the pipe the same, but move the cylinders closer - the center of the torus is also forced to move closer to the pipes until it reaches a contact point:

[image: Maximum bending without overlapping]

*Maximum bending without overlapping*

If you keep moving the cylinders the center of revolution of the torus becomes internal which causes overlapping.

To avoid that the cylinders need to be cut at 45 degrees and only part of the torus profile to be revolved:

[image]

Then the 3 parts can be glued back together:

[image]

[image]

Pushing farther turns the part into 90 degree sharp bend:

[image]

Here is a 3D preview of the possible cases:

[image]

Modeling the above cases by hand is not impossible it just requires a good knowledge of the Blender's modeling tools, like Knife tool, Mesh Boolean operations, Extrude, Spin operations etc.

**Geometry Nodes** is a good candidate for automating the process of creating this part but I used Blender's **Modifiers** stack for quick and dirty solution.

This is not the place to explain how the **Modifiers** work as it may get too long of a description.

You can download the .blend file bellow to quickly build your bend parts and study the file.
It is not *glitch free*, but it does the job. Just move the **Pipe Diameter** object left and right until you get a desired shape. The Object has **Custom Properties** that act as **Drivers** to some of the Modifiers' parameters which you can change in the **Properties Panel** (top left corner of the 3D Editor).

[image]